# How to make a website for IPhone in Visual studio 2010

Tags: iphone, asp.net, web

I want to make a website for IPhone, i am a .net devloper and i dont wan,t to use Desh Code for that,My question is How i will make my website for iphone in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Web development shouldnt be device dependant. A web site is intended to be used with any HTML browser (as much as they follow the w3c standarts), and im sure (though i dont own one) there's more than one browser, even for iphone

Comment: ok then how i will maintain the size of page for iphone.bcoz iphone screen is small how i will do this thing through Visual studio2010

Comment: its not about vs2010, or any other ide you can use. There are open-source / free frameworks to develop web sites aimed at mobile phones/ tablets generally. One of them is [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), which can be also integrated with asp.net development.

Comment: anyone will tell me why - vote for this queston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i face the same problem , and i have solution maybe will be useful for you 
but this solution for web development not application for iphone
if you ask for application no way to do it with out deshcode 
first thing go to your master and this and create this method 
   protected void checkdivice()
    {

```
    string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
    if (strUserAgent != null)
    {
        if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") ||
            strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") ||
            strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") ||
            strUserAgent.Contains("palm") || strUserAgent.Contains("nokia") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mobi"))
            {

            }
            else { Response.Redirect("mob/default.aspx"); }
        }
        else {  }
    }
    else { }
}
```

this method just check if the device is mobile or not 
now you must create web page that will dict the screen resolution and width 
css3 will be like:
`@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px)
  @media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 479px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 319px)`

Comment: ok, it mean we can make website for iphone mobile in vs2010 there is no need of DeshCode or MAC OS.

Comment: yes ,you can.
i make it before go from any mobile device to this link that i develop with framwork 2.0 [link](http://january-25.org)